# Two wordcloud2 on the same shiny page

Tags: r, shiny, wordcloud2

i'm trying to put two wordcloud2 in my shiny dahboard and the 2nd isn't showing

they are both in the body when i inspect the page

[image]

my script

```
library(wordcloud2)
library(shinydashboardd)
# Global variables can go here
n <- 1

# Define the UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
   box(wordcloud2Output('wordcloud2')),
   box(wordcloud2Output('wordcloud3'))
)


# Define the server code
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$wordcloud2 <- renderWordcloud2({
    wordcloud2(demoFreq)
  })

  output$wordcloud3 <- renderWordcloud2({
    wordcloud2(demoFreq)
  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

edit:
screenshoot when i use the answer script, there is no 2nd wordcloud

[image]

html output with both wordcloud div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <script type="application/shiny-singletons"></script>
  <script type="application/html-dependencies">json2[2014.02.04];jquery[1.12.4];shiny[1.2.0];htmlwidgets[1.3];wordcloud2[0.0.1];wordcloud2-binding[0.2.1];bootstrap[3.3.7]</script>
<script src="shared/json2-min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="shared/shiny.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="shared/shiny.min.js"></script>
<script src="htmlwidgets-1.3/htmlwidgets.js"></script>
<link href="wordcloud2-0.0.1/wordcloud.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="wordcloud2-0.0.1/wordcloud2-all.js"></script>
<script src="wordcloud2-0.0.1/hover.js"></script>
<script src="wordcloud2-binding-0.2.1/wordcloud2.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link href="shared/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="shared/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/bootstrap/shim/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script src="shared/bootstrap/shim/respond.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="wordcloud2" style="width:100%; height:400px; " class="wordcloud2 html-widget html-widget-output"></div>
    <div id="wordcloud3" style="width:100%; height:400px; " class="wordcloud2 html-widget html-widget-output"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

on this screenshoot there is no visilility; inherit on the 2nd wordcloud

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue, does it have a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not running into any issues with this. I can't run your code because it has a few errors (you wrote `shinydashboardd` instead of `shinydashboard`, and your UI doesn't run because the `dashboardPage()` function can't take two boxes are parameters) but if I just fix those errors it works fine:

```
library(wordcloud2)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
        wordcloud2Output('wordcloud2'),
        wordcloud2Output('wordcloud3')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
        output$wordcloud2 <- renderWordcloud2({
                wordcloud2(demoFreq)
        })

        output$wordcloud3 <- renderWordcloud2({
                wordcloud2(demoFreq)
        })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

(In the future, before posting a question with code, please make sure the code provided can run, unless of course the issue is with the code itself)

Comment: thx for your answer, i tried your code and it's the same problem only the first wordcloud is showing

Comment: The only thing I can think of is try updating the packages

Comment: last version on all package, i add the html page output, the 2 wordcloud are inside.

Comment: In that case you can report an issue to the wordcloud package authors and show them this code. Include any information about your environment